# Change default ignore rules when using az acr build

Tags: azure, docker

I am trying to access my git repo and perform some git commands inside the docker machine I built using `az acr build`. The machine builds correctly. But I get these warnings:

`WARNING: The login server endpoint suffix '.azurecr.io' is automatically omitted.`

`WARNING: Packing source code into tar to upload...`

`WARNING: Excluding '.git' based on default ignore rules`

`WARNING: Excluding '.gitignore' based on default ignore rules`

And as you would expect, later when I try and copy files from my working directory to the docker machine via the COPY task, the .git folder is not there. It seems like the default ignore settings for az acr build ignores the .git folder when it builds the docker machine. I checked the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-build

It doesnt seem to say anything about changing the default ignore rules. Any ideas how I could change this?

For reference here is the az command I run:

```
 az acr build \
            -t $(docker_repository_name)/$(docker_image_name):$(Build.BuildNumber) \
            --registry $(docker_registry_host) \
            --file src/Dockerfile /home/vsts/work/1/s/ \
            --platform $(docker_platform)
```

And here's the part of my dockerfile that tries to copy the .git folder:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

COPY [".git", "test/.git/"]
RUN ls test -la
COPY ["/", "test/"]
RUN ls test -la
```

Its worth noting I am not ingoring it in .dockerignore

Comment: This has nothing to do with using Git, it's all about `az`. (Convince `az` *not* to remove the Git files from the built image, and they'll be in the built image. But how you do that—convince `az` of anything—I have no idea.)

Comment: I actually figured out how to do it - You need to specificially include .git in your docker ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it! Your dockerignore file needs to reference .git you have to include !.git/** - so that it knows .git is defintely not meant to be removed from the context.